# AppSync always responds with "Failed to Fetch" and logs don't show anything

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-appsync

I have an AppSync API connected to a DynamoDB table and both are deployed using a CF template, but when I make requests to a particular resolver, it always hangs and then fails with "Failed to fetch". I've verified with IAM Policy Simulator that the role connected to the API is sufficient to run the scan specified in the requestMappingTemplate:

```
{
   "version": "2017-02-28",
   "operation": "Scan",
   "limit": 500
}
```

I've also verified with dummy data in the console that the below responseMappingTemplate works:

```
#set($uniqueStates = [])
    #foreach($item in $ctx.result.items)
        #set($found = false)
        #foreach($state in $uniqueStates)
            #if(!$found && $item.state == $state.name)
                #set($found = true)
                $util.qr($state.institutions.add({"name": "$item.name", "id": "$item.id"}))
            #end
        #end
        #if(!$found)
         $util.qr($uniqueStates.add({"name":"$item.state","institutions":[{"name": "$item.name", "id": "$item.id"}]}))
        #end
    #end
{
  "states": $util.toJson($uniqueStates)
}
```

I also followed directions to setup a logging role and attach it to the API. It will successfully create logs for introspection queries accessible through cloudwatch and set the log-level to ERROR.

When I go to the AppSync console for my API, all the settings appear as they should, but when I execute a valid query (as validated by the handy tools in the query building console) from the console (or anywhere else), it hangs and responds "Failed to fetch". The logs section also shows nothing. I'm tearing my hair out trying to discern why. Thanks ahead of time for your help!

Comment: in Chrome Developer Tools, the response always seems to come back as a 504 error...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It turns out that my problem was that my returned data from the response mapping template didn't match the schema, so it silently failed and resulted in a timeout error. Easy enough fix, but difficult to diagnose. The debug process I went through was by creating a new AppSync API devoted to one sample endpoint and step-by step made it the same as everything I had for the endpoint that was failing.

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar issue and Amazon support helped me to resolve it.  I am adding it here to help others who have a similar "failed to fetch" response.

It turned out that I was missing a required trust policy in the role that the lambda data source was using.  Once I added the below trust policy to the role my issue went away.

{
"Effect": "Allow",
"Principal": {
"Service": "appsync.amazonaws.com"
},
"Action": "sts:AssumeRole"
}

Answer (score 0):

What auth settings do you have enabled for the API? Also do you have a line in your response mapping template that outputs the payload after the template is evaluated? Something like a *$util.toJson($uniqueStates)*?

Comment: Thanks for the response. Yeah, I forgot to add it in my answer (edited to reflect that), but I did have "$util.toJson($uniqueStates)". I'm also using API_KEY authentication, and it works successfully for introspection queries.

Comment: Thanks for the details. One more question. Is there an active API Key listed on the settings page? The API key that comes by default is short lived so it may have expired and you would then have to create a another one. Another hypothesis might be to try to decrease your pagination size. If chrome is showing a 504 gateway timeout, it may be that the request is simply taking too long and that you need to decrease the page size.

Comment: Another idea. Can you verify that the role that is configured with the data source attached to the resolver is configured correctly to allow access to your DynamoDB table. Further can you verify that the table exists and that the arn is correct in the data source page?

Comment: These are al great ideas. Unfortunately, the active API Key (which is generated in my CF template) does appear and match. The table only has 2 elements in it, and using the default limit doesn't seem to make a difference. Likewise, I can verify that the table exists at the correct ARN and a paranoid tracing and IAM Simulator testing of the role attached to the data source allows Scan on the appropriate table...

Comment: Can you share a request id. In the response of a timed out a request there should be a header "aws-request-id" that would help debug.

Comment: the x-amzn-RequestId header was "e5d17e64-8f69-11e8-8d47-0fad1769ae83". Are you an AWS employee? If so, I'm super impressed by the fact that you guys are helping out on stackoverflow!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/176667/discussion-between-mparis-and-samuel-duzett).